# Display Drop down options for Values saved in Backend

Tags: magento

we created custom module and we saved list of Product `Brands` & `Models` in Backend. In below image, `Apple, sony, samsung` are Brands & `iphone4, iphone4s...etc` are Models.

[image]

**Brands**

[image]

**Models**

[image]

we want to create dropdown options for both Brands & Models in frontend, once we select Particular Brand from **1st drop-down box** , than only associated Models should display in **2nd Drop-down box**. as [here](http://www.dailyobjects.com/select-mobile-tablet-case-model)

[image]

**Company/Brand/Block/Frontend/View.php**

```
class Company_Brand_Block_Frontend_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
     protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/breadcrumbs');
        $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
        if ($headBlock) {
            $product = $this->getProduct();
                $title = $product->getMetaTitle();
            if ($title) {
                $headBlock->setTitle($title);
            }
            $keyword = $product->getMetaKeyword();
            $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
            if ($keyword) {
                $headBlock->setKeywords($keyword);
            } elseif ($currentCategory) {
                $headBlock->setKeywords($product->getName());
            }
            $description = $product->getMetaDescription();
            if ($description) {
                $headBlock->setDescription( ($description) );
            } else {
                $headBlock->setDescription(Mage::helper('core/string')->substr($product->getDescription(), 0, 255));
            }
            if ($this->helper('catalog/product')->canUseCanonicalTag()) {
                $params = array('_ignore_category' => true);
                $headBlock->addLinkRel('canonical', $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, $params));
            }
        }

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
    public function getProduct()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(310)
            ->getProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_phone_case', 1);

            $products=$collection->getFirstItem();

            $product =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($products->getId());
            $p=Mage::registry('product');
        if ($p=='') {Mage::register('product', $product);}
            return  $product;
        }
```

I will give 50 Bounty if it works for me.

Comment: what is the DB table structure for both?

Comment: @SumanSingh I dont have much idea about this, can you please tell me where i need to look to check db structure, so i will check and inform you. is in database or in module files ?

Comment: In database , where you are saving the brands and models.

Comment: @SumanSingh we have like this : http://prntscr.com/brxvwq & http://prntscr.com/brxwne